# What does "Many an airy castle" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Many an airy castle, which we builded in our youth, was a mere vagary of the imagination “a mere fiction of the fancy” created out of nothing, and to nothing soon returned.

What does “Many an airy castle” mean here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also note that *builded* is incorrect here; it should say *built*.

Comment: @WendiKidd Into the 17th century Great Mother Language had not yet decided whether *built* or *builded* should be the correct form (David Crystal has a [blogpost](http://david-crystal.blogspot.com/2011/01/on-built-and-builded-in-kjb.html) on this), and some Victorian writers (the source of this passage was published in 1897) were fond of employing *builded* to lend their work a poetic or scriptural air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *airy castle* is a quirkily-phrased reference to...

> [castles in the air](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/castles-in-the-air) *- plans that have very little chance of happening.*

The usage *many an X* has been [covered before on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/many-a-year-vs-many-years) (it's just a poetic/dated variant of *many Xs*), so in total the excerpt is simply a roundabout way of saying...

> *Many fanciful ideas we had in our youth had no basis in reality, and were soon discarded.*