# Maybe a typo mistake

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, determiners

I was reading news and found a mistake. I have just wanted to confirm that, as it does not sound natural to my ears. I feel that **the article(a)** or maybe **this word(many)** are not sounding naturally here. The writer should have used one of them instead of both, please check and let me know your feedback.

I read this in a newspaper:

> At a time when she is expected to win **many a trophy** for her
>   performance in queen (a Bollywood movie).

As per my opinion, these both options could be possible:

> At a time when she is expected to win **many trophies** for her
>   performance in queen(a Bollywood movie).
>
> At a time when she is expected to win **a trophy** for her performance in
>   queen(a Bollywood movie).

Both below sentences are sounding fine to me, but first one does not sound natural to me.

Comment: It might be a bit of a surprise, but "many a trophy" is actually grammatical. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/many-a-year-vs-many-years, and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25555/usage-of-many-vs-many-a.

Comment: The meaning of *many a* is "a large number of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question +1.

The word *many* here is used for the *large indefinite* number. And at times, this sort of phrase is used to describe that something which is after *many* is expected in large quantity. I'm familiar with this structure.

> ...expected to win many a trophy for her performance...

Simply means she's expected to win many trophies. It's the other way to tell that.

I found a reference here...

> [many a (adj)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/many+a) - each of a large indefinite number; "many a man"; "many another day will come"

Another interesting thing is on [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/many-a-time). It defines *many a time* is equal to **many times**. Compare *many a trophy* = *many trophies* this way.

Comment: This is all correct, except a "many a" is not an adjective. It seems to some kind of determiner.

Comment: @Max well the dictionary says that and as I have the link I had to write what's there. Though I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

**Many a** is certainly standard English.

Simply [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+many+a) it shows the meaning.

Both your alternatives are also grammatical, but the original is certainly correct as well.

There is many a way to say things in English! :)